# 'My bad' vs 'My bag'

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, slang, colloquialisms

Over the years I've noticed a non-insignificant amount of people use the term 'My ba**g**' to admit guilt when getting something wrong (i.e. 'Mea culpa'). For example:

"Happy Birthday!"
"My birthday's not for another 2 days"
"Oh, my bag"

I understood the correct — albeit slang — term to be 'My ba**d**'. My question is why is 'My ba**g**' so often used instead?

Is it simply a misnomer, perhaps stemming from 'That's not my bag' (i.e. Not my area of expertise [hence I got it wrong])?

Edit: I live in the UK, but understand the etymology of 'My ba**g**' comes from the US.

Comment: Add a location please. Is it the USA? Which state? Which city/town/shack? I'm presuming this is the US because of the phrasing but if it's the UK, Australia, South Africa etc. you should tell us.

Comment: Do you have any examples (e.g. recordings) of this?

Comment: I have never heard "my bag" in this sense.

Comment: Are you "noticing" these people online? It's an easy typo to make.

Comment: This sounds like a mondegreen, people have jmust misheard the phrase.